# Buffer error during multiple trim (audio) ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, trim

Am trying to trim and concatenate multiple sections of an audio file. After a number of searches, this seemed to work.

```
ffmpeg -i dd.3gpp -filter_complex "[0]atrim=start=00:00:00.060:end=00:00:46.580[a];[0]atrim=start=00:0:50.250:end=00:01:50.670[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3
```

However it didn't take long before I realised that it only worked when intervals between the trimmed sections were short. Changing the timestamps of the second trimmed section into this,

```
ffmpeg -i dd.3gpp -filter_complex "[0]atrim=start=00:00:00.060:end=00:00:46.580[a];[0]atrim=start=00:03:23.250:end=00:06:50.670[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3
```

It keeps throwing this error at me.

> [out_0_0 @ 000001df0a98d6c0] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
>   [out_0_0 @ 000001df0a98d6c0] 1000 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.

[Report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zvW0YQuB6PK9u1doKVFg2-P_Qb_QwUlt/view?usp=drivesdk)

```
ffmpeg version git-2019-12-12-f58bda6 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 36.101 / 56. 36.101
  libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
  libavfilter     7. 68.100 /  7. 68.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'dd.3gpp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2019-12-14T18:42:01.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:08:46.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-14T18:42:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (aac) -> atrim
  Stream #0:0 (aac) -> atrim
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    com.android.version: 7.0
    TSSE            : Lavf58.35.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.100 libmp3lame
size=     170kB time=00:00:10.84 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=21.7x    
size=     256kB time=00:00:19.77 bitrate= 106.0kbits/s speed=19.7x    
size=     256kB time=00:00:28.17 bitrate=  74.4kbits/s speed=18.7x    
size=     512kB time=00:00:39.69 bitrate= 105.7kbits/s speed=19.8x    
[out_0_0 @ 000001df0a98d6c0] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
[out_0_0 @ 000001df0a98d6c0] 1000 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
size=    1280kB time=00:01:33.09 bitrate= 112.6kbits/s speed=22.9x    
size=    1521kB time=00:01:37.27 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=22.9x    
video:0kB audio:1520kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.023446%
```

Is there something that am doing wrong? All suggestions are welcomed.

[image]

Comment: Add -report and rerun command. Upload report file and share link.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the response. Could you please elaborate a little? Am more of a beginner. By report, you mean the command line message?

Comment: Yes, `ffmpeg -i dd.3gpp -filter_complex "[0]atrim=start=00:00:00.060:end=00:00:46.580[a];[0]atrim=start=00:03:23.250:end=00:06:50.670[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3 -report`

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question with the report now. I couldn't figure out how to add the text file.

Comment: @Gideon You can use a pastebin site and provide the link or just [edit] your question and add it there.

Answer (score 4):

So after playing around with the two codes for a while,

```
ffmpeg -i dd.3gpp -filter_complex "[0]atrim=start=00:00:00.060:end=00:00:46.580[a];[0]atrim=start=00:0:50.250:end=00:01:50.670[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3

ffmpeg -i dd.3gpp -filter_complex "[0]atrim=start=00:00:00.060:end=00:00:46.580[a];[0]atrim=start=00:03:23.250:end=00:06:50.670[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3
```

it appears the buffer error has nothing to do with whether or not the time intervals between the two trims ware short.

Rather, the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) of the timestamps seemed to have been the issue. I changed the timestamps into `S+[.m...]`, instead of `[HH:]MM:SS[.m...]`

```
ffmpeg -i dd.3gpp -filter_complex "[0]atrim=start=0.060:end=46.580[a];[0]atrim=start=203.250:end=410.670[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3
```

and the error is not showing up anymore. The first code worked alright because all timestamps fall within the seconds column (`00:00:ss.m..`) I think. I must say I have not the slightest inkling as to why the formatting plays a role in this instance. Maybe the professionals here could explain better.

Comment: Got the same issue. Changed hour to seconds and the isue went away. In my case, I needed to cut a scene over one hour after the start and the duration was about 10 minutes, so I don't think it's related to a small timestamp. I'm using `4.3.1-2020-10-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev`.

Comment: I get this error despite using seconds, and without the `trim` and `atrim` filters - I'm using `-ss` and `-to` to trim the inputs directly.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the issue is that the colon ":" is used for separating arguments by filter_complex. So you need to escape it.

The excellent answer from https://superuser.com/a/1145796

Provides the following character escape solutions:

`"trim=start='00\:00\:01.23':end='00\:00\:04.56'" "trim=start=00\\\:00\\\:01.23:end=00\\\:00\\\:04.56" trim=start=00\\\\:00\\\\:01.23:end=00\\\\:00\\\\:04.56`

Have fun!