# FFmpeg&FFPlay: Option `start`&`end` of filter `trim` have trouble parsing time duration string but `-ss`&`-to` works perfectly

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm tring to **preview cut video before process it** on Windows, this `Cut.bat` is what I tried:

```bat
@echo off
@cd/d %~dp0

REM Entered by user
set startTime1=5
REM Entered by user
set startTime2=00:05
REM Entered by user
set toTime1=13
REM Entered by user
set toTime2=00:13

echo [96mPreviewing...press any key to process[0m

REM No, ffplay don't support `-to` option
REM ffplay  -i in.mp4  -ss %startTime1%  -to %toTime1%  out1.mp4

REM Result: 8 seconds long video preview, start from 00:05 (correct)
ffplay  -i in.mp4  -vf trim=start=%startTime1%:end=%toTime1%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -af atrim=start=%startTime1%:end=%toTime1%,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS

REM Result: 13 seconds long video preview, start from 00:00
ffplay  -i in.mp4  -vf trim=start=%startTime2%:end=%toTime1%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -af atrim=start=%startTime2%:end=%toTime1%,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS

REM Result: failed to preview so I commented it out
REM ffplay  -i in.mp4  -vf trim=start=%startTime1%:end=%toTime2%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -af atrim=start=%startTime1%:end=%toTime2%,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS

REM Result: failed to preview so I commented it out
REM ffplay  -i in.mp4  -vf trim=start=%startTime2%:end=%toTime2%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -af atrim=start=%startTime2%:end=%toTime2%,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS

pause

REM Result: All of them are 8 seconds long videoes, start from 00:05 (correct)
ffmpeg  -i in.mp4  -ss %startTime1%  -to %toTime1%  -c copy  out1.mp4
ffmpeg  -i in.mp4  -ss %startTime2%  -to %toTime1%  -c copy  out2.mp4
ffmpeg  -i in.mp4  -ss %startTime1%  -to %toTime2%  -c copy  out3.mp4
ffmpeg  -i in.mp4  -ss %startTime2%  -to %toTime2%  -c copy  out4.mp4

pause
```

The document said [all of them support](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay-all.html#trim) [time duration expression](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax), it's true for `-ss` and `-to`, but not working well with `start` & `end` of `trim`

Since `startTime` & `toTime` are entered by user (myself) so I hope to write it freely instead of using strict format

- Did I wrote it wrong? If so, what's the correct syntax?
- Is there any other simple and/or reliable way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1145777/use-ffmpeg-filter-complex-trim-with-time-duration-including-hours-and-minutes), it's an escape trick (I have to say the escape syntax of ffmpeg is a good example of spaghetti

The correct syntax would be:

```bat
set startTime2Es=%startTime2::=\:%
set toTime2Es=%toTime2::=\:%

ffplay  -i in.mp4  -vf "trim=start='%startTime2Es%':end='%toTime2Es%',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -af "atrim=start='%startTime2Es%':end='%toTime2Es%',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS"
```

instead of

> ffplay  -i in.mp4  -vf trim=start=%startTime2%:end=%toTime2%,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -af atrim=start=%startTime2%:end=%toTime2%,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS